# ASP.NET MVC - Adding CSS to your view (inside of the view not an external .css file)

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVCs. I want to ask if there is a way to add CSS inside your view, but not using an external .css file? For example: `table {border: 5px solid red;}` (Just like you would do it in a normal HTML-CSS project)?

Comment: Assuming you chose the default Razor view engine, it's still just basically html, so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich yes I use Razor ... Still if i write `table, td, th {
    border: 5px solid red;
}` I get it written on my page... like normal text

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich and this is css not html

Comment: Are you using the style tag?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich oh haha, now I see that I missed it, thanks

Answer (score 15):

Consider using sections. In your layout add:

```
<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
</head>
```

Then, in your view:

```
@section Styles
{
    <style type="text/css">
        table { border: 5px solid red; }
    </style>
}
```

This will have the effect of adding this style tag into the `head` of your HTML where it should be, instead of littering `style` tags throughout your code.

Answer (score 4):

> You can also define `CSS` in `razor` view by using **style** tag as shown below:

```
<style>
    table {border: 5px solid red;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some like this.

```
@Html.Label("Hello World",new{@style="your style code"})
```